# Type Mismatch 13 error when trying to activate a sheet

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

Everything I've read shows that I'm correctly denoting my variable and calling the sheet I want to activate. The last line is where I am getting the type mismatch. At that point CPIDws = CERN000006. I read somewhere that it might be problematic that the name is letters and numbers, but haven't found a way around it.

```
Sub Create_tab()

Dim newWS As Worksheet, CernWS As Worksheet, CPID As Variant
Dim Template As Worksheet, CPIDclm As Long, CERNdata As Range, CPIDcheck As Variant
Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long, i As Integer, CPIDws As Worksheet

Set Template = Sheets("Template")
Set CernWS = Sheets("CERN ID's")
'Set lngRow = 1
'Set lngCol = 1


CernWS.Activate
Cells(1, 1).Select

Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Set CPID = ActiveCell

    'create a new sheet as a copy of the template
    Sheets("Template").Copy _
           after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    'Name the new sheet as the current CPID value from CERN ID's worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = CPID
    Set CPIDws = ActiveSheet

    'interigate AAA Data and update the new sheet with the data specific to the current cpid
    Sheets("AAA Data").Activate
    Cells(2, 3).Activate
    Set CPIDcheck = ActiveCell

    Do
        If CPID = CPIDcheck Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
            Set CERNdata = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))
        End If

        Sheets(CPIDws).Activate
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At that point CPIDws = CERN000006.

No it doesn't. :)

You've declared `CPIDws As Worksheet` but you're using it as an argument to the `Sheets` method, which takes either an index (integer) or name (string) value.

Thus, type mismatch.

Try simply `CPIDws.Activate`

or, arguably you could do the redundant: `Sheets(CPIDws.Name).Activate`

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) may also come in helpful, as it's generally recommended not to rely on `Active` (cell, sheet, etc.) or `Selection` when it can be avoided (which is almost always the case, except for some instance when you use the `Selection` as a method of input. But generally, your macro should probably never need to *Select* or *Activate* any cell other than that which the user had selected for input.  In your case, since you're beginning at `Cells(1,1)` and controlling the iteration entirely through code, it's not at all necessary to `Select` or `Activate` anything.

Comment: Well, I know I had tried CPIDws.Activate at one point and was getting the same error, but as you said, that did work now that I've tried it again.

I haven't written VBA in a while, but I have always used *Activate* or *Select.* I will for sure take a look at the thread you referenced.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Beginners seem to use Activate and Selection. All changes can be accomplished without ever activating a sheet. Directly referencing an object is good programming.